# base64 decode run into hex 00 interrupted

Tags: c, base64

I have one Base64 String `U2FsdGVkX19+UwN4AAAAALe0aaTselLYGDsTUQk2cSY=` and I want to convert it into `53616C7465645F5F7E53037800000000B7B469A4EC7A52D8183B135109367126`.
But when it did base64 decode to hex it will interrupted as a `53616C7465645F5F7E530378`
when I changed  00000000 to 10101010, it work!
So I think it was base64 decode with hex zero problem, but I don't know how to fix it. BTW I write C language.

My code as below

```
char *unbase64(const char *input, int length, int *out_len)
{
    BIO *b64, *bmem;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    memset(buffer, 0, length + 1);
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if(b64 == NULL) {
            buffer[0] = '\0';
            return buffer;
    }

    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf((char *)input, length);
    bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    if((*out_len = BIO_read(bmem, buffer, length)) <= 0) {
            buffer[0] = '\0';
            return buffer;
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    BIO_free_all(bmem);
    return buffer;
}

char * toHex(unsigned char *s) {
    size_t i, len = strlen((const char*)s)*2;
    char *buff = malloc(len + 1);
    if (buff != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < len ; i += 2) {
            sprintf(&(buff[i]), "%02x", *s++);
        }
   }
   return buff;
}

int main()
{
  char * b64 = "U2FsdGVkX19+UwN4AAAAALe0aaTselLYGDsTUQk2cSY=";
  int unb64_len = 0;
  char *unb64 = unbase64(b64, strlen((char *)b64), &out_len);
  char * hex_str = toHex(unb64);
  print("hex string: %s\n", hex_str);
  return 1;
 }
```

Comment: The decoded string has embedded NUL (0) characters in it, you can't use `strlen` to get the length of such a string because it stops at the first 0 it finds. Pass `out_len` to your hex function and use that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes! I tried your comment and it works! Thanks